# Can I use Google SignIn token throughout the application?

Tags: android, spring-boot, google-signin

I have implemented android app with google signin. After successfully signed in to google, Client app receives token and send it to the spring boot API. It verifies the google token and get user information.

My questions are following:

1. Can I use this token to authorise my spring boot api as well? If yes, then how?
2. If no, then what’s the other option?
3. Do I have to create access token and refresh token for all other requests between client and server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not suggest to use the google token multiple reasons:-

1. That token will have limited expiry time
2. That token will not have the required information that you might need it later on server side.
3. As your application grows you might need to add roles for security purposes that will not be fulfilled by google token
4. Your need for expiry time will differ from google's
5. You might need to encrypt your token that cannot be used by some other application.

Good idea is to validate the google token on server side and then create your own token and refresh token. This will give you more control about your application.

Comment: Then if google access token expires, then I have to do silent signin. Is it correct?

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible to get new access token with user consent. In that case you will have to redirect user to the consent screen once the token has expired.